# Selenium, Firefox, and geckodriver does not auto scroll for click method

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, webdriverwait

I am using Selenium, Maven, TestNG, and Java to run automated tests on Firefox. Previously, I used Firefox v52, gauva v21, testng v6.9.10, selenium-java v3.4.0, and commons.io v2.1 (coming from pom.xml). I upgraded to Firefox v60, which means updating all the dependencies. The problem I am having is that when I run the same tests (regardless of tests), they fail because the element is not being brought into the viewport, which was done by default in Firefox v52. I can interact with the element, such as getting the text or the size of all elements on the page, but I can not click. Here is a reference to what's happening https://www.hskupin.info/2017/12/15/element-interactability-checks-with-geckodriver-and-firefox-58/. I tried updating the moz:webdriverClick but I'm guessing that's only available for Firefox v58 (maybe v59).

Here are the dependencies in my updated pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons.io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

my java file

```
public class Assassinate {

protected WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
    String customProfile = System.getProperty("customFirefoxProfile");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(customProfile));

    FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "resources/geckodriver");
    fo.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    fo.setProfile(profile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(fo);
    driver.manage()timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    getDriver().quit();
    TemporaryFilesystem.getDefaultTmpFS().deleteTemporaryFiles();
}

@Test (groups = {"test"})
public void firstTest () {
    getDriver().get("someurl");
    getDriver().findElement(By.id("id")).click();
}

}
```

I removed DesiredCapabilities and updated to Firefox Options. I also added the path to the geckodriver. This gets me as far as opening the url and I get a success, but it will not click the element because it is out of view. If I choose an element that is in view, I can click it fine. I would ultimately like to run my tests headless, which I can do, but this issue is halting everything. Has anyone else been able to get around this or find a fix? I'm not getting any errors, so no help there. TIA.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue that you were facing. My Selenium script works fine with the Chrome Driver but fails to  click the button when I swap it out with the gecko driver. So just to support Firefox, I have to add overload all the clicks to scroll and click which is huge overhead. Did you find your answer by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

### guava-23.6-jre

If you are using the following *Selenium* maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You don't explicitly need to use the following *guava* maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

As **selenium-java-3.11.0** contains **guava-23.6-jre**

[image: guava_jar]

---

### auto-scroll for `click()`

To invoke `click()` on an element, **auto-scroll** does happens only if the desired element is **visible** within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

The relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) would have given us some idea whether the desired element was visible within the HTML DOM or not. However as per best practices when you open a new page, before clicking on an element induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
@Test (groups = {"test"})
public void firstTest () {
    getDriver().get("someurl");
    new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id"))).click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can not post the html because of proprietary reasons. After doing some more testing, I did find some more information. If I take the same code (pom.xml, setup method) and just change the test to run on a basic website, the driver will find links that are not in the viewport and click on them. The difference that I find with my issue is that what I am trying to click is inside an iFrame. Again, I can confirm the driver is seeing the link outside of the viewport because I can .getText() and it will return the link text. However, it can not click until it's visible.

Comment: I'm not sure how that was misleading? The application I am testing did not change. The only change was upgrading Firefox, Selenium, and its dependencies. This tells me that there is a change in how Selenium (or geckodriver) interacts with the DOM. With the previous version, this worked without error.

Comment: @codeavenger07 See you have a lot of wrapper functions, e.g. `getDriver()` and the answer's can't be canonical unless you show us the definition of those. We also have no data/clue how you executed in the _previous version_. However as per the information you provided within the question I have tried to help you out.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding, but I will try to answer. On line 5 of my java file above I have the getDriver() method. Then in my beforeMethod, I create a new Firefox driver before every test. What other definition do you need? As far as the previous version, I listed the dependencies and versions in my first paragraph and then listed what I upgraded to. This is the only thing that changed. If you need html code, I'm sorry but I can not provide that.